# Should i bury an old piece of cloth it has Kalimah written on it and also has an image of holy Kabbah on it?

Tags: clothing

It  is torn at many places and also has dirt marks on it should I wash and keep it or are there other ways also.

Answer (score -1):

It isn't really a good idea (my own opinion), but either of the two options is alright. You can have them buried in a neat place (I'd prefer this) or burn them if you think you won't be able to keep them properly or they may get in the wrong hands, and probably used, later, as rags which isn't right.